# I can no longer select my QBO company in the API Explorer

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have been developing an app using the QBO v3 API, and everything has been fine until this morning.  Now, when I am in the API Explorer, instead of a dropdown to select which of my QBO companies to use (I currently have four), I get a message that says "You're logged in with an account that does not have a QuickBooks Online subscription. Please try another account."

The only thing that I have done since the last time it worked was that I was signed out from inactivity, and I signed in again.  I have signed in to my actual QuickBooks Online company (using the same login info) and I can still get in to the company and use QuickBooks Online for all four of my companies, just not the API Explorer.

Has anyone had this problem before?  Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a support request for some website. Please contact their customer support. This site is for programming questions.

Comment: I have.  The problem is that their customer support sucks, and I don't expect to hear back from them very soon.  I was hoping that this community of developers might have some experience and be able to help me out.  I thought it may be possible that I have done something wrong that I am just unaware of that maybe some *helpful* member of this community could help me out.  But thanks for the downvote, that's cool too.

Comment: Hum, yes, maybe I should downvote... Try your in chat if you can find a room that fits more or less.

Comment: Also, this IS actually listed on Intiut IPP's website as one of their official channels of support, hence the intuit-partner-platform tag.  Sorry if that wasn't you that actually downvoted me, it's been a frustrating week working with this API and I just need some help.

Comment: What they list as support channels doesn't change what this site is for.

Comment: Is this site not meant for developers to ask other developers for help with programming issues?  I'm not trying to be snarky, I just don't understand what is wrong with my question.

Comment: You got it: programming issues. Login problems on third party sites don't qualify as programming.

Comment: 1. My original thought when posting was that maybe I had done something wrong (in my code) while trying to use the API that I didn't understand, and that someone else may have done the same thing and had some advice for me.

Comment: 2. Is there a better vertical of StackExchange to post this question on?

Comment: If there's a code aspect to this, are we supposed to guess the code you're using? If there's some sort of API  key involved, did you check if it's still valid?

Comment: Yes, there is some sort of key involved, it is my QB Online user account, which I noted that I checked in the original question.  And, no, I wasn't expecting anyone to *guess* what the code might be, I was hoping that someone had come across this symptom before and could point *me* to the part of my code that might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuit did finally respond to me.  This was a problem on their end that I had no control over.